# Printing the letter capitalized

Tags: assembly, x86

I wrote an x86 assembly program that, when the user enters a lowercase letter, prints the letter that comes before it in uppercase. For example, if `p` is input, the output should be `O`.

Unfortunately, the code doesn't work. It prints different ASCII chars instead.

Here is a part of my code:

```
LEA DX,MSG1
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H

    MOV AH,1
    MOV CHAR,AL
    INT 21H


    SUB CHAR,33
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to store the character in `CHAR` before it has been read.

This:

```
MOV AH,1
MOV CHAR,AL
INT 21H
```

should be:

```
MOV AH,1
INT 21H
MOV CHAR,AL
```

Comment: _"not working"_ (if that's what you meant to say) doesn't really tell us anything. _In what way_ is it not working?

Comment: When i enter b, instead of printing A as an output, it prints a character like smiley face...etc from the ASCII. This is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Mistake was

```
MOV AH,1
MOV CHAR,AL ;<------before character read
INT 21H ;character read
```

And here is valid code:

```
  ;character read
    MOV AH,1
    INT 21H
     MOV CHAR,al

    ; check range {our range begins from b}:
    lea bx,CHAR
    cmp byte ptr [bx], 'b'
    jb skip
    cmp byte ptr [bx], 'z'
    ja skip

    mov dl,[bx]
    sub dl,33 
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
     skip:
```

Comment: Sorry but could you explain, do i have to use byte ptr[px] ? I'm a total beginner so i don't know what that instruction means

Comment: @user3102872  It can depends compilers. But anyway we have to use that when there is no way assembly to know size. So byte ptr [bx]  will make sure that we will compare byte, not word(16bit) . For example on mov CHAR,al assembly will see that al is 8bit so it will use move byte ptr.But on cmp as you see it cant detect

Comment: Byte ptr will simply indicate 1byte at [bx] address